# How to call a javascript function in the component?

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components

i have a javascript function that i wish to run after the component is loaded.
this is the function:

```
higlightCurrentRecordId : function(component, event, helper) {
    var id=component.get("v.idforHighlight");   

    var e=document.getElementById(id);    

    var node = document.createElement('div');        
    node.innerHTML = '<label class = "redDot" >&#9679;</label>';       
    e.appendChild(node);    
},
```

how can i trigger this function after the component is done loading?

please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use `Afterrender` In RENDERER Section

```
({
afterRender: function(component, helper) {
   this.superAfterRender();
   helper.higlightCurrentRecordId(component);
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call this method either on `aura:doneRendering` or `aura:valueInit`. doneRendering is called everytime anything changes on your screen, even resizing. valueInit is called only on loading completion. so its upto your requirement which one to use.

> aura:doneRendering

```
<aura:handler event="aura:doneRendering" action="{!c.higlightCurrentRecordId}"/>
```

> aura:valueInit

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.higlightCurrentRecordId}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. 
seems like i need to use the `aura:valueInit` but when i do i get the error: `Uncaught Action failed: c:AccountRow$controller$higlightCurrentRecordId [Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null] ` and its not because there isn't a record as such, it just doesn't load i guess before valueInit starts.
to test it, i added a button and whenever i press it, it works